# A very strange thing in the tempdb

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

In all the following scenarios on my laptop, all the tables in the SSMS Tables folder will be deleted from *tempdb*:

1. Instance Restart;
2. Stop & Start SQL Server Service;
3. End Task SQL Server process in task manager;
4. OS (WINDOWS) Restart.

I have no problems with the above.

But …

The following scenario is very interesting:

First, I create a table in *tempdb*:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE Test_Table
(ID INT,
Title VARCHAR(100));
GO
INSERT INTO Test_Table
VALUES
(1,'Test01'), (2,'Test02'), (3,'Test03');
GO
```

Then I exit SSMS and shut down Windows.

A few days later …

Turn on my laptop.

When I get into SSMS, I'm surprised to see that there is a `Test_Table` with its records in the tempdb.

Why? I did not create such a table in the model database.

I thought so much about this.

Can the following explanations prove this hypothesis?

You should be aware that Windows shut down is much faster than restarting.

It is likely that in Windows restarting, the SQL Server service will also be restarted, and to end the service, it should release the resources it has, as well as empty the contents of *tempdb*.

But in the Windows shut down process, the Windows shut down service is likely to be responsible for releasing resources, and in fact kill all processes, and obviously there is no accident in the tables in the Tables folder of *tempdb*, Because the SQL Server service does not restart.

I tested this in versions SQL Server 2019, 2017 and 2008.

Do you think your guess is correct?

I'd be happy to express your opinion about this.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Your question has **contradicting information**: *"...I'm surprised to see that there is a Test_Table with its records in the **tempdb**."* and *"...Why? I did not create such a table in the **model** database."*. Please clean up your question and ensure you have documented what your exact issue is. Otherwise your question might be closed as as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 4):

You probably created another test_table in the model database, so then [TempDB inherits that on startup](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/creating-tables-stored-procedures-tempdb-permanently/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the "Shutdown" is in reality a Hibernate?

Apparently, Windows can do this by default, but it is supposed to end user processes, according to https://www.howtogeek.com/262325/why-is-windows-hibernating-instead-of-fully-shutting-down/.

Anyhow, check the errorlog file from when you "started" Windows. Do you have a new file? Then you have a startup and something creates this temp table at startup (startup proc in master db or model db). If not, then it wasn't a real windows startup. - [Tibor Karaszi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi)